# Python xlwt read value

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wb.add_sheet('SHEET1')

#that value I want to get in my fu
sheet.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula('E4*H8'))   # for example value == 4 

def fu(value):   
    x = value + 1
    return x                               #How I can get 5 in answer

fu(???)

wb.save('E:/')
```

Good day. How can i get the value of  the cell (0, 0), before I save the file and use it(int or float) in my function.
Or I must save the file and open it with xlrd, get the value, and after then open file to run my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading stackoverflow I found the answer from autor of xlrd & xlwt:
The modules can't read the formulas.
Solution is count values in python and then write it on new cells:

```
x = 2
y = 2
sheet.write(0, 0, x*y)

c = x*y
def fu(c):
    z = c+1


sheet.write(1, 1, fu(c))
```